# How do I connect the vertices of a regular polygon?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have a diagram that is just the 4 vertices of a square, all colored.  I want to connect the vertices so that the square has edges.  How do I do this?

My code currently looks like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45]
    \foreach \a in {0,90,180,270} { %\a is the angle variable
    \draw[line width=.7pt,purple,fill=purple] (\a:1.5cm) circle (2pt); }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please could you complete your code fragment so we have a complete minimal example we can compile?

Answer (score 6):

Probably the simplest is to place coordinates where the circles are and then just join them afterwards. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45]
  \foreach \a in {0,90,180,270} { %\a is the angle variable
    \draw[line width=.7pt,purple,fill=purple] (\a:1.5cm) coordinate (a\a) circle (2pt); }
  \draw [line width=.7pt,purple] (a0) -- (a90) -- (a180) -- (a270) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: join the dots]

You don't want to draw the lines at the same time as the circles as you don't want the square itself to be filled, I assume.

Note that, as it stands, your code doesn't use the library you load. However, you could use that library to draw the picture in another way by making the square a node and then adding circles at the anchors at each of its four corners:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (s) [minimum width=3cm, minimum height=3cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, line width=.7pt, draw=purple] {};
  \foreach \i in {north west, north east, south west, south east}
    \draw [fill=purple, purple, line width=.7pt] (s.\i) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is identical to that above.